# how to return a datatable if a register number exists

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, datatable

I am trying to display a grid if the user entered register number exists in database, if the register number does not exists this means that I need to display one label also.i am a new one in asp.net,so please help me.
Here is my code below.

```
public DataTable madhrasaViewByRegNo(string viewByNo)
{
    try
    {
        madhrasaInfo infomadhrasa = new madhrasaInfo();
        object decobj = new object();
        if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
        }
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("madhrasaViewByRegNo", sqlcon);
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@regNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = viewByNo;
        decobj = sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (decobj == null)
        {
            decStuId = decimal.Parse(decobj.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable dtbClass = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("madhrasaViewByRegNo", sqlcon);
            sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@regNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = viewByNo;
            sqlda.Fill(dtbClass);
            return dtbClass;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return null;
}
public void gridfillByNo()
{
    madhrasaSp spMadhrasa = new madhrasaSp();
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    dtbl = spMadhrasa.madhrasaViewByRegNo(TextBox2.Text);
    gvstuResult.DataSource = dtbl;
    gvstuResult.DataBind();
}
public void regSearch()
{
    madhrasaSp spmadhrasa = new madhrasaSp();
    spmadhrasa.madhrasaViewByRegNo(TextBox2.Text);
    if (madhrasaSp.decStuId > 0)
    {
        gridfillByNo();
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Invalid Register Number";
    }
}
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    regSearch();  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Dont you just set the grid view's EmptyDataText to 'Reg No Dosent exist'. It will solve your ploblem.

Comment: in design view select gridview then in properties tab goto EmptyDataText and set the value which will be displayed when no data is present in gridview.

Comment: i tried that , but i didnt get any result if the grid is empty

Comment: well change your  function madhrasaViewByRegNo to return an empty datatable instead of null

Comment: and y u think so? If u want to show it ina label you will be adding 1 more control. isnt it? Gridview comes inherintly with this feature just for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EmptyDataText="register number not available">
</asp:GridView>
```